# Ender 3, unable to level the heating bed

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

I have an Ender 3 3D printer.

I am having an issue with leveling it, everything I do does not make any change.

The right side of the bed is higher than the left side, that will make me loosening the right side springs completely.
I’ve worked with this printer before and I know it’s should not be like this.

1. The printer is sitting on a leveled surface.
2. I have 90° in each of every connection of the stands.
3. X-Axis is corresponding to the upper stand.
4. I’ve replaced the regular bed cover for 4 mm ״milky” glass.
5. I’ve replaced the springs to the stronger ones.
6. I’ve modify the location of the Z-switch to the lowest corner of the bed.

Comment: The frame is prob bent. Can you post a pic of the left and right side bed leveling screws. See this is why I'm an advocate of 3 point leveling (tramming).

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: Note that a printer itself hasn't to be placed on a [leveled table top](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/7892/5740).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the homing and then do the leveling how much thread you have left that passes the tuning wheel? Verify this on all the four wheels. If you have no thread left then you may consider to lower the Z end-stop.
Check also the Y gantry to see if it is parallel to the base, and make adjustments if needed.