# How do I reset the bed leveling data?

Tags: bed-leveling, creality-cr-10

I have a Creality CR-10 S5 which is using Marlin firmware 1.1.6.

I recently got a level to level my printing bed, good high precision one.

Afterwards it was printing as if my bed was not level.

I assume that the 3D printer has old bed leveling data stored from its previous calibration.

- How do I clear this old data?
- Can I enter new data manually?

The printer doesn't have auto leveling with the current firmware.
I tried the old firmware, and the auto-leveling system didn't level the print bed.

I have no bed leveling sensors.

Comment: You are implying manual Unified Bed Leveling procedure of Marlin? Or are you using a bed leveling sensor? Or a bubble level? Please elaborate the question to include more information.

Comment: It sounds like you are literally leveling the bed to gravity (you said you used a level). This is **not** what you want. The actual definition of bed leveling is making the bed parallel to the XY motion of the print nozzle and an appropriate distance to the Z=0 position. It doesn’t matter (within reason) if the bed is leveled to gravity.

Comment: Using bubble level for the bed is useless (unless you level the whole printer frame, which you should not do), you need to level in reference to the frame, see [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/7892/).

Comment: Apparently my floor isn't level, so I re-leveled it, making it as unlevel as the floor. Have to test it later tonight.  Any one recommend a good bed leveling device.  However, the side that was too high I had to tighten a lot so that's a good sign.

Comment: Do you send `G29` to your printer or do you use `G28` in print startup? I use a dial gauge to level my bed.

Comment: @cybernard Don't level with the bubble level you bought, level or better said tram the bed with the provided screws relative to the nozzle. The nozzle moving over the X axis is your level, make sure the bed is parallel to the X-axis. You don't need the bubble level!

Comment: @Trish G29 does nothing on my printer.  Yes I have G28 in the startup code.  I tried several variations and all it says is OK, but does nothing.

Comment: Did you customize your firmware?

Comment: @Trish I downloaded a new firmware provided by creality. 1.1.6.  Is this firmware considered custom?  So it is not the one it came with. How does it differ, I don't know except it is now compatible with OctoPrint Pi.

Comment: Please link to the firmware you downloaded. Some fimrware does *not* have G29 active. You need G29 to use mesh bed leveling.